# External storage issue with mounted state and correct permission

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

On a Samsung Galaxy Mini (Android 2.3), I'm unable to install a 100+ MB APK via Eclipse (always some error, and nothing really helped; usually it says insufficient_storage, even though there is 300+ MB free space on the external storage i.e. on the SD card in this case, and install location is set to PREFER_EXTERNAL).

So I copied the APK to the SD card via USB connection, and then unmounted USB from PC. Then with File Manager I opened the APK, and installed it. Before install, **it does not display** the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to be approved (maybe this is the problem?).

When I run it, I get the following error when trying to write to my folder (`getExternalFilesDir(null)`) in the external storage:

"Unable to create external files directory"

It displays it twice in logcat.

I use `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` before doing anything and it returns `MEDIA_MOUNTED` properly. It is logged in logcat at the same place as where the "Unable to create..." log appears. Rebooting the phone does not help, and toggling USB connection on/off with PC also doesn't (these were mentioned in other stackoverflow topics).

The beginning of my Android manifest is the following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    package="com.example.apps.iik"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
```

Is it normal that installing it from APK does not display the write_external_storage permission? Maybe the app gets installed without this permission? But as far as I noticed with other devices, then it doesn't recognize the external storage as "mounted", at all.

Comment: Is the APK file itself over 100MB? Not an answer but if you're going to upload this to Play Store do you know they only accept < 50MB and you need to do expansion file for more?

Comment: Yes, this is only our debug APK. It will be <50MB, and we will add the rest of the data in an Expansion APK. The handling code for that is not yet integrated to my software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android 2.3, many OEMs had set their own thresholds for low storage (Moto devices won't let you install from store if APK size*4 > available storage.)

If you installed via some file manager or app installer app, it probably won't show any permissions. But you can always see the permissions by going to Settings > Apps, and the click on your app.

Also, before writing into a file, first create it by doing `file.createNewFile()`.

Comment: To be precise, the APK is 127MB, and SD card has 300MB free space. Do you think that the device rejects creating the application's external storage folder (with the message "unable to create...") because it checks how much free space is there? Copied APK is 127 MB (and forgot to delete it after install), install takes another 127 MB, so only 43 MB is left after install. Could this be the reason for rejecting creating external storage folder?

Comment: 46 MB, to be accurate, but not that it matters.